# CakePHP filter queries by user's business accounts

Tags: cakephp, user-accounts, cakephp-2.4

I'm new to CakePHP 2.4 and trying to understand conceptually if I'm on the right track before I start building the following.

By default, when a User first logs in to his online account, he sees Orders, Invoices, and Documents for ALL ACCOUNTS that he has access to.  Using an Account dropdown and the button "Go", he can filter Orders, Invoices, and Documents for only ONE ACCOUNT.

Currently, pre-CakePHP, this is all handled in query logic.  The User-Account (N:N) relationship is in the database.  Any active Account_Id is stored in the SESSION.  ***What is the CakePHP to do this?***

The Model looks like:

```
User hasAndBelongsToMany Accounts
Account hasMany Orders
Account hasMany Invoices
Account hasMany Documents
```

1.) Should I code the relationship between Users and Accounts in a Model (hasAndBelongsToMany) or in the ACL/Auth component (User is ARO, Account is ACO)?

2.) To show ALL ACCOUNTS, what is the best way to "query for" this filter and apply it to each Model.  Or is that done automatically by the Model?... or by ACL/Auth?

3.) To show ONE ACCOUNT, is storing an Id in the Session still the best approach? ...or should I be thinking about a new set of actions in each of the Orders, Invoices, and Documents Controllers?

Answer (score 0):

I will support you with set of links to CakePHP cookbook which clarifies all your queries:
First of all you should read about [linking models](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html).

Next thing is creating correct database and tables in there following [CakePHP conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html)

Another step is ["baking" your models/controllers/ views](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/code-generation-with-bake.html)

After that step all you need to do is just [play arround with data you get from your models](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html)

To be honest you dont have to code any relations at all if you just correctly create your database with corect foreing key names which Cake will detect and build relations through interactive shell (you will be asked if you want console to create relation for you through cake bake ).

```
$this->ModelName->find('all')
```

will give you all data of given ModelName and also all related data,
using

```
$this->ModelName->recursive=-1
```

will make your model to retrive only data from ModelName without any related data.

In practice some things will probably work for you out of the box but some of things you will have to simply implement. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks scx.  Of course I've been reading up on cakephp quite a bit.  I'm still confused how I can apply this to my example of Users and Accounts.  For the functionality I described, should Accounts be built in Auth/ACL?  What is the best way to apply the filter for ALL ACCOUNTS or ONE ACCOUNT?  Thanks for your prompt response!